# IDEA: Move caret to end of line after using shortcut to assign local variable?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-completion

On Mac, after you introduce a local variable by using the context menu or keyboard shortcut, the caret automatically goes to the end of the line so you can simply press enter and start typing on a new line. On Windows it seems to want to stay at the end of your variable name. I've tried to find this in the settings and Googled for it but can't find any resources on how to also do this on Windows.

As an example if I type something like `new Object();` and ask IDEA to automatically introduce a local variable for it, it will automatically go to the variable declaration to name it. On Mac, your caret is moved to the end of this line after the semicolon once you are done naming the variable. On Windows, it is placed after the variable declaration. So if you ended up having a line such as `Object someObject = new Object();`, the caret is placed at the beginning of the variable assignment, after the equals sign. Hitting enter will then just introduce a line break between the declaration and assignment.

It can fairly annoying to deal in situations where I need to introduce multiple variables with method calls.

Here's a gif just to illustrate what happens on Windows:
[image: Pressing enter creates a new line]

I'm aware that you could just hit END to go to the end of the line but the Mac implementation of this is massively more convenient. I assume it's hidden somewhere in the settings - but where?

Comment: Can't reproduce. On Windows pressing Enter after the variable name moves the caret to the end of line. Try with the default settings: File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...: https://i.imgur.com/kbrkC7w.png.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. Furthermore, I just realized it's also happening on Mac as well. Sometimes it will move to the next line, other times it does what I described in the OP. After some playing around it looks like it expects an empty line on the next line (the gif above had indents already in place). So trying to do it on 2 lines in a row won't work, but skipping a line and doing it again seems to work. Very strange. Will use shift-enter instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can use SHIFT+ENTER and you will have pretty much the same result if I understand your issue corretly

Comment: Close, I'd rather have it like it is on Mac, but if it turns out it's not possible, I'll mark this one as the answer and live with SHIFT+ENTER.